# Pass array as attribute from form

Tags: yii

In my model I have attribute - specifications:

```
    class Category extends CActiveRecord
    {
        private $_specifications = array();

        public function getSpecifications()
        {
                    return $this->_specifications;
        }

        public function setSpecifications($specifications)
        {
                    $this->_specifications = implode(', ', $specifications);
        }
```

So I want specifications to be an array.

My view file:

```
<div id="specifications" class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'specifications'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'specifications',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50, 'name'=>'Category[specifications][0]', 'class' => 'clonedInput')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'specifications',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50, 'name'=>'Category[specifications][1]', 'class' => 'clonedInput')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'specifications'); ?>
</div>
```

When I send form I get an error:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
...
public static function encode($text)
84     {
85         return htmlspecialchars($text,ENT_QUOTES,Yii::app()->charset);
86     }
```

I've tried to disable encoding:

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'specifications',array('encode'=>false, 'rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50, 'name'=>'Category[specifications][0]', 'class' => 'clonedInput')); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'specifications',array('encode'=>false, 'rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50, 'name'=>'Category[specifications][1]', 'class' => 'clonedInput')); ?>
```

But in that case it's another error:

```
Array to string conversion
...
2216                 $html .= ' ' . $name . '="' . ($raw ? $value : self::encode($value)) . '"';
```

Can anybody give an advice, what should I do to pass an array from form? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you pass an array to a single textfield? What should it display?

You can can create a virtual attribute for that.

In the model:

```
private $_specifications = array();

public function getSpecifications()
{
    return implode(', ', $this->_specifications);
}
```

The view can remain untouched.

**Edit:**

Of course you need a setter too, if you want to be able to write to the attribute.

```
public function setSpecifications($specifications)
{
    $this->_specifications = explode(', ', $specifications);
}
```

Please refer to http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/

Comment: So then where should I put calling this function?

Comment: Nowhere, because of that i wrote `The view can remain untouched.`;) Yii automatically checks for variables and for virtual attributes (getXyz) when you specify them. You can also write `$model = new MyModel(); echo $model->specifications;`

Comment: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: I've added: if (isset($this->_specifications))
Got an error: Property "Category.specifications" is read only.

Comment: Can you update your post with the new code and updated methods?

Comment: Important: `private $_specifications = array();`. Thats why you get the error.

Comment: I've corrected, but still have an error: 
Property "Category.specifications" is read only.

Comment: Then you somewhere write to this value, too. See my updated post

Comment: Thanks for code!
But with this approach I have also an error. See my updated post, in this way it works normally.

Comment: You have to copy correctly;) `return implode(', ', $this->_specifications);`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `specifications` attribute is an array, you should simply make a loop to display corresponding inputs, e.g. :

```
foreach ($model->specifications as $s)
{
  echo Chtml::textField('Category[specifications][]', $s, array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50, 'class' => 'clonedInput'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'specifications',array('encode'=>false, 'rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50, 'name'=>'Category[specifications][0]', 'class' => 'clonedInput')); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'specifications',array('encode'=>false, 'rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50, 'name'=>'Category[specifications][1]', 'class' => 'clonedInput')); ?>
```

I think the specifications will be displayed twice.